# How do you make each cell inside of a table clickable using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html-table

I searched around but I couldn't find an answer to my question. I am trying to create a tic tac toe game for a school project. I created a table with 3 rows and 3 columns using HTML and I'm trying to make it so that when I click on each cell an x appears. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use JQuery's `click()` method on each table cell, [see documentation](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery?

```
$("table td").click(function() {
   $(this).html("x");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put an id on the table and then select with jquery from there.

HTML:

```
<table id="ticTac">
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
#ticTac tr td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#ticTac tr td {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#ticTac tr td").click(function() {
        $(this).html("x");
    });
});
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/opL45vLr/